# Unable to connect to MongoDB in Spring Boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

I've just created a very basic Spring Boot project using Spring Tool Suite with `mongoDB-reactive` dependency and run the app but, I keep getting the following exceptions

> 2019-11-27 00:31:19.699  INFO 11988 --- [localhost:27017]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread
>   while connecting to server localhost:27017
>
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:410)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]  at

I am using Spring Boot (2.2.1.RELEASE)

Inside `applications.properties` I've added the following line

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`MongoSocketOpenException` occurs when the spring boot app cannot connect to mongo db using the given connection details (or default localhost and 27017 port)

Check whether the MongoDB instance is running using mongo shell
if fails check for mongo db server config for listening interface ip (to enable listening to all interfaces - use net config as

`net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017`

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't have a separate mongoDB instance running. I am expecting that spring boot would use an embedded MongoDB. Also, where to configure the 'Net Config' ?..

Comment: You have to add the dependency for embedded mongodb

Comment: use 
      
      <dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      
    </dependency>

Comment: @ashanshamika  Where should this net config be set in my spring boot app which is using embedded mongo for test purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you want embedded mongo, add the dependency
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.flapdoodle.embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

Alternately you can easily install mongo instance on your local.

Comment: please check included dependency in you pom  embedmongo-spring <dependency>
    <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
   <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the dependency I added is test scoped. Things have worked after removing it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to connect to mongo service present in k8s, from other sprint boot app, I understood that SpringBoot has some auto configure features it was trying to connect to localhost:27017 by default during app start up, to skip it I had to exclude it in application yaml:
spring.autoconfigure.exclude:org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration